# Как реализовать нечто вроде reinterpret_cast, но без необходимости указывать все спецификаторы?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, x86-64

Устал постоянно писать reinterpret_cast с указанием всех спецификаторов (const, volatile). Придумал шаблон.

```
template<typename toT, typename T>
static inline auto toType(T val) {
  using t2 = typename cond< 
    is_const<T>,
    typename cond <
      log_and< is_pointer<T>, is_pointer<toT> >,
      const typename remove_pointer<toT>::type *,
      toT 
      >::type,
    toT
  >::type;
  return reinterpret_cast< t2 >(val);
}
```

Как видите, получилось нечто монструозное, и это только с учётом спецификатора const. Код не по стандарту, так как всё самописное, но суть не меняет. Код работает.

Можно ли более простым способом менять интерпретацию данных?
Суть такая: допустим есть переменная типа `const volatile char * A`, нужно изменить доступ с побайтового до, допустим целочисленного, то есть `const volatile int * A`. Простой `reinterpret_cast<int*>(A)` отбросит и `const` и `volatile`.

Решение на основании ответа:

```
template<typename TValue>
struct remove_pointer<TValue *> {
  using type = TValue;
};

template<typename T>
auto toType(void* p) {
  return reinterpret_cast< typename remove_pointer<T>::type *>(p);
}

template<typename T>
auto toType(const void* p) {
  return reinterpret_cast<const typename remove_pointer<T>::type*>(p);
}

template<typename T>
auto toType(volatile void* p) {
  return reinterpret_cast<volatile typename remove_pointer<T>::type*>(p);
}

template<typename T>
auto toType(const volatile void* p) {
  return reinterpret_cast<const volatile typename remove_pointer<T>::type*>(p);
}
```

Comment: *"Как видите, получилось нечто монструозное"* - еще было бы хорошо расписать, что эта штука должна делать, приведя [mcve]. Вообще говоря, необходимости в использовании `reinterpret_cast` в реальном коде практически нет, и *"Устал постоянно писать reinterpret_cast "* говорит о том, что вы постоянно делаете что-то не то.

Comment: А как вы переводите данных из памяти в указатели на структуры? Например, при работе с ACPI-таблицами?

Comment: Ну пишите приведение в С-стиле, получится практически то же самое... Только вот вам сейчас гуру от стандарта расскажут о strict aliasing и что указатели на один тип просто так нельзя переводить в указатели на другой...

Comment: Если имеется ввиду получение указателя на POD структуру, которая лежит в буфере с байтами, то для этого лучше создать объект такой структуры и скопировать кусок буфера посредством `memcpy`, не забыв проверить тривиальность этого класса (unchecked conversion в терминах Ада). Если же делать оверлей (overlay в терминах Ада), то предварительно будет необходимо проверить корректность выравнивание указателя и задействовать `std::launder`. При этом ни на каком этапе `reinterpret_cast` не понадобится.

Comment: Для преобразования указателя на байт буфера в указатель на `void` для передачи в `memcpy` или для последующего преобразования в указатель на структуру достаточно `static_cast`.

Comment: Зачем мне забивать память копиями, если исходные данные нужно просто иначе интерпретировать?

Comment: Я не считаю себя гуру стандарта, однако `strict aliasing` действительно очень сильное ограничение. В С++ в принципе нельзя просто так кастовать `reinterpret_cast` одни объекты в другие. *"исходные данные нужно просто иначе интерпретировать"* - это вы себе простреливаете ногу. Это не какая-то прихоть стандарта, это следствие требований к выравниванию данных. Причем отступление от этого требования больно бьет даже на архитектуре x86, которая традиционно поддерживала невыровненный доступ, но при использовании векторых инструкций предъявляет более строгие требования.

Comment: Вы вообще о чём пишете? Есть некие данные, которые необходимо по-разному интерпретировать. Изначальный доступ по-байтовый. Всё! Никаких SIMD не требует, доступ изначально невыровненный.

Comment: *"данные, которые необходимо по-разному интерпретировать"* - Для начала вам следует уяснить, что С++ этого не разрешает. Причем это не подразумевает прямого запрета кастовать что-то во-что, просто в результате вы получаете неопределенное поведение. Интерпретировать данные по-разному легально можно только в узком количестве сценариев и при соблюдении определенных условий. А требования к выравниванию и SIMD - это то, что обычно на практике приводит к проявлению проблем некорректной интерпретации данных.

Comment: Интерпретация происходит в строго заданном сценарии, а не наобум. При работе с ACPI-таблицами даже CRC нужно проверять, а уже потом интерпретировать данные как таблицу. Вы вообще не о том думаете и, как следствие, ответа я от Вас не ожидаю. Не тратьте моё время, своё время и место в БД ресурса.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147925/discussion-between-adokenai-and-user7860670).

Comment: Простой сишный cast `const volatile int * A = (__typeof__(A))your_pointer;` чем не подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Четыре перегрузки самостоятельно разберутся с `const` и `volatile` квалификаторами:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T *cast(void *p) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T *>(p);
}

template<typename T>
const T *cast(const void *p) {
    return reinterpret_cast<const T *>(p);
}

template<typename T>
volatile T *cast(volatile void *p) {
    return reinterpret_cast<volatile T *>(p);
}

template<typename T>
const volatile T *cast(const volatile void *p) {
    return reinterpret_cast<const volatile T *>(p);
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    void *p = &i;
    const void *cp = &i;
    volatile void *vp = &i;
    const volatile void *cvp = &i;
    
    std::cout << typeid(cast<int>(p)).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(cast<int>(cp)).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(cast<int>(vp)).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(cast<int>(cvp)).name() << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ cast.cpp 
>
> $ ./a.out 
> Pi
> PKi
> PVi
> PVKi
> ```

**P.S.** Пример приведён для `(const) (volatile) void *`, но точно также можно работать с `(const) (volatile) unsigned char *`

Comment: Суть Вы поняли, но нужно не только указатели приводить, а вообще любые типы. Например указатели к size_t и наоборот. Хотя, попробую использовать Ваш вариант с доработкой. Выглядит перспективно. Благодарю.

Comment: ¿С таким подходом, если пойдут указатели на указатель, то будете 16 перегрузок делать?

Comment: @user7860670, в вопросе было про указатели в сырую память. Так что указатель на указатель надо будет делать вложенными: `cast<>(cast<>())`. Каждый вызов отвечает за свой уровень косвенности.

Comment: Спецификаторы конечно остаются, но `cast<uint8_t*>` делает тип `uint8_t**`, а не `uint8_t*`. Можно конечно указывать в параметре шаблона тип без звездочки, но тогда легко запутаться... Видимо без условий не обойтись...